# How can I determine all the files referenced by a bash script?

Tags: bash, file, reference

I'm modifying someone else's series of interdependent bash scripts that have lots of hardcoded paths to scripts and resource files. I'd like to be able to determine the paths of all the files, scripts, commands that are referenced after calling the top-level scripts. Ideally I'd get a list full paths, and where each path is referenced. It'd be kinda like running ldd, but for scripts.

Does anyone know a technique for this?

Comment: In general, questions asking us to 'recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam'.

Comment: From a practical point of view, it'll be very hard to do a thorough job of analyzing all the names in the files because there are many ways of disguising names, such as building up pathnames from component pieces. Also, almost any sequence of characters could be a file name. The chances are, your system has a limited repertoire of file names, but you'll need to develop appropriate heuristics for the system you're working with. There are probably local conventions that will make it easier to work out what's what, but without us having access to far too much code, we won't be able to do much.

Comment: I edited the question to avoid asking for a tool - does that work?

Comment: I'm imagining some technique that operates at a lower level, and doesn't parse the scripts themselves. It'd catalog all file descriptor references and all commands that get called. Maybe within bash itself or some process monitor - I don't know enough to imagine how this would actually work. I'd grep the massive output for non-standard paths to narrow down to likely problem spots.

Comment: Yes, the rephrased question is now more acceptable.

Comment: What level of detail are you prepared to get to? Using `truss` or `strace` with output to file and following child processes would get you information about all the files being used — but there'd be a lot of irrelevant garbage in amongst the nuggets you're after. You might be able to limit the logged activity to the system calls you're interested in (primarily `open` and `exec`), but there'd still be a lot of detritus to search through. You could ignore most of the failed opens (but some might be relevant). Also, it will only report on the stuff actually used, not that which could be used.

Comment: Thanks! `strace` looks like it might be perfect. I should be good with the `-f` option to follow child processes and the `-e trace=open` option to log only calls to `open`. Alternatively, all file access can be logged with `-e trace=file`. The log shows full paths to files, even when bash finds them using PATH.

BTW how do I get the question off hold?

Answer (score 1):

You could use bash's `-x` option to print everything that it's doing.  That's not going to give you what you want directly, but it might be enough that you can grep your way to an answer.  Look at the lines that begin with `+` below.

It really depends on what you mean by "all the files that are referenced": just all the sub-scripts that get run, or the config files that they read, or the data files that they operate on too?

```
~ $ cat test.sh
echo "In test2.sh"
. test2.sh
./test3.sh
~ $
~ $ cat test2.sh
echo "In test2.sh"
~ $
~ $ cat test3.sh
echo "In test3.sh"
~ $
~ $ bash -x ./test.sh
+ echo 'In test2.sh'
In test2.sh
+ . test2.sh
++ echo 'In test2.sh'
In test2.sh
+ ./test3.sh
++ echo 'In test3.sh'
In test3.sh
```

Comment: This obviously only takes one of the possible code paths through any conditional.  For any nontrivial script, that's going to be inadequate.

Comment: Thanks Ewan, this helps a bit. It output steps in the script with env vars expanded so that can help unmask some paths more easily.

Comment: @tripleee Yes I agree. For my current needs at least, there are few branches so anything I can do will help.